# ! LaTeX Error: File `trajan.sty' not found

Tags: ubuntu, latex, tex-live

I'm not sure how to get the Trajan style font for my latex project.  All blogs I've read say I need to use `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`.

Is there any way I don't need to download 5 Gb of texlive and just specify the Trajan font style?

Thanks!

Comment: If you would use vanilla texlive instead of the ubuntu package, you could use `tlmgr` to manage which packages should be installed. Something like `tlmgr install trajan` should install the package

Comment: I'm not familiar with using vanilla texlive.  I am using ubuntu on a windows computer.  Would your approach still be possible?

Comment: Sure! You can get texlive from http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html (I would always recommend the version from the TUG website over the stuff packages for ubuntu because it is much more up-to-date)

Answer (score 0):

Packages [`trajan`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/trajan) and `fontenc` should be enough, as in [this TUG article](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/trajan/).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trajan}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
{\trjnfamily %
TRAJAN EXISTS IN UPPERCASE ONLY. THE TRAJAN BUNDLE PROVIDES FONTS BASED ON THE CAPITALS CARVED ON THE TRAJAN COLUMN IN ROME IN $114$ AD. MANY TYPOGRAPHERS THINK THESE RANK FIRST AMONG THE ROMAN'S ARTISTIC LEGACY.
}%

Trajan exists in uppercase only. The trajan bundle provides fonts based on the capitals carved on the Trajan column in Rome in 114 AD. Many typographers think these rank first among the Roman's artistic legacy.
\end{document}
```

Beware because not all the characters that you may need are available in Trajan (I recommend to read the [package guide](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/fonts/trajan/trajan.pdf)).

Comment: And how to install the package?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz do you agree `tlmgr install trajan` is the command?

Comment: Sure! ___________________